# Keep pixels crisp when rotating object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, transform, raster

I noticed that when rotating an object in Photoshop the preview of the image has nice and crisp pixels, but when I rotate the image and finish the transformation it adds an annoying blur. Is it possible to disable that or find a good workaround?

The carrot stays nice and pixelated in the preview.

[image]

But it ends up being blurred when I confirm the transformation.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be something called transform Image Interpolation, but I cant figure out where the setting is or if it is 100% the same issue as I am having.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/pixels-shifting-after-applying-transform-in-photoshop?rq=1
I would like to know how to get what is shown in this post...

Comment: I had a problem like this recently. Mine was because the original object itself was too small. Maybe try resizing the object before rotating.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

When transforming, before accepting the transformation change the interpolation at the top menu to **Nearest Neighbor**:

[image]

Comment: Ah its in the menu of the transform, I did not realize! Thank you!

Comment: @PAWPS if Daniel has answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.